Gravitational potential at any point
What's wrong in this derivation of potential at any point? Its showing GPE at any point is +ve but its supposed to be negative right?
Supoose a object is being moved from infinity to a point at distance $r$ from the center of earth. What's the GPE?
Direction of $F_\text{ext}$ and $\mathrm{d}x$ is opposite. So,
$$   
\begin{aligned}
W &= \int F_\text{ext} \cdot \mathrm{d}x \cdot \cos180° \\
  &= \int -\frac{GMm}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x \\
  &= \frac{GMm}{x} |_{\infty}^r \\
  &= GMm\left(\dfrac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{\infty}\right) \\ 
  &= \frac{GMm}{r} 
\end{aligned}
$$
As GPE is defined as the energy to take any object from inifnity to asked point, I have taken

External force in opposite direction ($+x$ axis) of Gravitational force as kinetic energy should not be changed.
direction of $\mathrm{d}x$ is in $-x$ axis
So,angle is 180°
Upper limit : $r$ lower limit: Infinity

Still the ans is +ve. Please explain what's the wrong assumption here?

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/658425/ https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/498978/
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/gpot.html#gpi

This question is similar to: Gravitational potential negative sign confusion. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: Why does this line integral give the wrong sign? and Contradiction on gravitational potential energy. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

When you did the integration (first line in the text box), you've used the limits $0$ to $\infty$. In the "standard" derivation, you integrate from $\infty$ to $0$, because the potential at a point is the work done when moving an object from infinitely far away (where it has GPE = 0 by definition) to that point.
